# Overriding array(list) type conversions in Spring Data R2DBC

Tags: postgresql, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

I'm using Postgres as my datasource and I've created a custom Spring converter for a property that holds a list of my custom objects:

```
@Slf4j
@WritingConverter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomObjectListToStringConverter implements Converter<List<CustomObject>, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(@Nonnull List<CustomObject> source) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(source);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred while serializing list of CustomObject to JSON.", e);
        }
        return "[]";
    }

}
```

Conversion goes smoothly but `IllegalArgumentException` is raised in `getArrayType` method of `PostgresArrayColumns` class because my custom type is not a simple type.

Is there a way to circumvent this guard for some property?

Comment: Looking for help in customer converter. Can you please take a look on this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70584887/spring-r2dbc-custom-json-converter-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no override possible because `DatabaseClient` considers collection-typed values as values for Postgres' array fields. Please file a ticket at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/ to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. For now I created a class which holds a list of objects and created a custom converter for it, also I've opened the issue on Github.

Comment: @NikolaB, I cannot find the issue on Github, could you add a link?

Comment: @QwertZuiopü - Looking for help in customer converter. Can you please take a look on this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70584887/spring-r2dbc-custom-json-converter-not-working

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported intentionally based on the documentation.

> Please note that converters get applied on singular properties. Collection properties (e.g. Collection) are iterated and converted element-wise. Collection converters (e.g. Converter<List>, OutboundRow) are not supported.

Source: [spring-data-r2dbc mapping reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/reference/mapping.adoc)

**Solution:**
Create a wrapper class (complex type) as follows:

```java
class CustomObjectList { 
  List<CustomObject> customObjects;
}
```

Then, you apply a converter `Converter<CustomObjectList, String>` and vice versa.

```java
public class CustomObjectListToStringConverter implements Converter<CustomObjectList, String> {
```

Comment: The workaround seems correct, but I don't think the observed behavior is intentional.
From my understanding of the documentation, a converter for the custom type (that is, `Converter<CustomObject,String>`) should be applied element-wise to the elements of the property `List<CustomObject>`.

Comment: @magiccrafter - Looking for help in customer converter. Can you please take a look on this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70584887/spring-r2dbc-custom-json-converter-not-working